# asyncio fails to connect to RabbitMQ

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm learning thenextquant quant framework, but always get connection error while connecting to RabbitMQ. after some troubleshooting, i found asynico/aioamqp module always prompts error:An open stream was garbage collected prior to establishing network connection; call "stream.close()" explicitly.
 while trying to connect to RabbitMQ server, RabbitMQ is up and running and other client can connect to it without any error.

Then I followed the hello world example from aioamqp(https://github.com/Polyconseil/aioamqp/blob/master/examples/send.py) to write a test program, then reproduced the error.

```py
import asyncio
import aioamqp


async def send():
    transport, protocol = await aioamqp.connect(host="127.0.0.1", port=5672, login="guest", password="guest", login_method="PLAIN")
    channel = await protocol.channel()

    await channel.queue_declare(queue_name='hello')

    await channel.basic_publish(
        payload='Hello World!',
        exchange_name='',
        routing_key='hello'
    )

    print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
    await protocol.close()
    transport.close()



asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(send())
```

```
(venv_380) appledeMBP:Market apple$ python hello.py

An open stream was garbage collected prior to establishing network connection; call "stream.close()" explicitly.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 31, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(send())
  File "/Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 608, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "hello.py", line 14, in send
    transport, protocol = await aioamqp.connect(host="127.0.0.1", port=5672, login="guest", password="guest", login_method="PLAIN")
  File "/Users/apple/.virtualenvs/venv_380/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aioamqp/__init__.py", line 59, in connect
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
  File "/Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/asyncio/trsock.py", line 82, in setsockopt
    self._sock.setsockopt(*args, **kwargs)

OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 1):

finally I found it's caused by version of Python. the issue is gone once using 3.6 instead of 3.8 which result in connection issue with aioamqp.connect()